# check if a web service using authentication is available for a specific login (combo of user and password)

Tags: c#, web-services

I am doing a http get to an url of a webservice, which is actually a WCF hosted in IIS using binding transport with credentials.
I want to check if I can do a call to that service using a specific login. How  can write the httpget request to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting `HttpWebRequest.Credentials` property? Something like `request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "password")` . See link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.credentials.aspx